Windows server always changes time every hour
I have a server, Windows Server 2008 R2 system, physical machine, Hyper-V is turned on to run several virtual machines. Every hour, the host machine will adjust the time backward by one hour, that is, 5:37 to 4:37. If left unchecked, it will keep changing every hour, resulting in a huge discrepancy with the real time. I have disabled the Windows Time service, and the log shows that it is the system process (PID 4) changes it. Please help.
I have never had this problem on any other computer, just happend on this one.


What is your NTP source set to?

What is your time-zone set to?

@spikey_richie keep default time.windows.com, and sync with Internet is unchecked.

@user165568 it is +8:00 shanghai/hongkong.

"sync with Internet is unchecked" why? It needs something to sync to...

Use Process Explorer to see what services are running in PID4. Break them into groups to see which service is affecting the time. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/why-is-system-pid-4-having-so-much-disk-activity/f0491068-4edb-4e6f-8dd9-c7c8c7489a40

@spikey_richie this is not matter, sync or not sync, it always change time each hour.

@user165568 no service here, pid4 never run any service.

What does Process Explorer show for Process 4?

@user165568 How should I say, no Services tab here.
